# Modifying MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database

How do i modify a MySQL table where hundreds of records are being inserted every second without having any downtime / losing data or errors .

Ex: Adding a new field

Thanks

Comment: What kind of modification are you trying to make?

Comment: Are the records only being inserted into that table or there is also a SELECT on that table?

Comment: I was told only inserts , does it change anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gut feel says that you should avoid modifying the table. An alternative would be to add your column to a new table and link to the original table to maintain referential integrity, so the original table remains untouched.

Another, fairly typical approach would be to create a new table with the added column, swap it out with the old table and then add the data back to the new table. Not a great solution though.

MySQL gurus will likely disagree with me.

Answer (score 0):

Well if only inserts i think best would be:

```
CREATE TABLE the_table_copy LIKE the_table;
ALTER TABLE the_table_copy ADD new_field VARCHAR(60);
RENAME TABLE the_table TO the_table_backup;
RENAME TABLE the_table_copy TO the_table;
```

But first make a copy of it and try with copy if fast enough. Then do it on real live thing! :)

Comment: Well...the_table will not have any of the data in it.  That seems like a problem.  And it will cause downtime for a (short) period of time between the RENAME statements.

Comment: downtime can be 0.002 ms, and table can be empty, Tarek said he only insert not select from it

Comment: well he didn't say he only insert, he said he was told only inserts i see. Well Tarek if there is no selects and updates then i think this would be ok.

Comment: [rename] was added in MySQL 5.1.7 but was found to be dangerous and was removed in MySQL 5.1.23

Comment: @Alain Collins he didn't specify version of MYSQL however i told to first try on a copy of table. REMOVE in MYSQL is maybe dangerous for database rename but again also eval is dangerous in PHP if you don't know to use it but sometimes its essential.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would lock the table, add the field, unlock the table. There would then be a little delay on the inserts, but it wouldn't be much of a hassle I guess.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the DDL for adding the field will automatically lock the table.

Answer (score 0):

when you say "add a field" you are creating new columns, or just updating values in a column? Both are quite different things. If you are merely updating a column, change your data model to support multiple versions of the same row in the same table, and keep adding the new rows at the end of the table. This gives you the best read-write concurrency.

Other than that, you can take a look at the "Handler Socket" method.
http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.com/search/label/handlersocket

Comment: add a new column not updating values of a column

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to add a column, there is no reason for that to require downtime.  The table will be locked for the duration of the ALTER TABLE statement (milliseconds).  Any DML submitted during this time will have to wait, so it could briefly impact performance, but it should not cause any exceptions, unless the code somewhere is explicitly checking for locks.

Comment: Milliseconds?  Please tell me how to add a column to my 300M row, 50GB table in milliseconds (in stock mysql).